# What's the minimum memory usage that a Nexus S requires?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s

I have a friend running a rooted Nexus S with approximately 350 Mb RAM. In normal everyday usage, he says he uses about 300 Mb of that memory. There is this game he is trying to play that requires roughly around 150 Mb.

I was just wondering if it is possible to clear up enough memory so that he can play that game comfortably? What exactly is the minimum amount of memory required to keep the phone running?

Comment: That's not how it works. I'm sure someone will give the full specs, but Android handles the RAM, it keeps things alive as long as it can for speed/efficiency but will kill them if there is a demand (like a game). Frankly the Nexus 5 can probably run any game at the moment!

Comment: I should probably add that when playing the game, it will eventually freeze up. And at that time, his memory is full.

Comment: Ahhh that's a real problem then. That should not happen. It could be down to an issue/incompatibility with the game itself. It could be down to using the Android Runtime (ART), or the app being poorly optimised for Nexus hardware. Do other games do it..?

Comment: Sorry. I read nexus FIVE, not nexus S. That's why I was confused in previous post. This device may not be powerful enough to run the latest games. I've an S4 here and that has 2 gigs of RAM and even still poorly optimised games (Gameloft I'm looking at you) lag, stutter and crash.

Comment: Recently, this game has updated and this game started freezing for my friend after the update. I don't know if the game was redesigned to use more memory now, or if it is just a memory leak in the game itself. On my Droid 4, I am still perfectly fine and have recorded around 150 MB of Ram usage when running the game. That's why I'm curious to see if we can cut down on the memory usage and test if he can still play this game :)